# Playwright - when clicking on the login button, the username and password is deleted

Tags: playwright

I am using playwright and js to automate some tests. I find that when I enter and username and password and click login, the username and password are then deleted. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the test script is faster than the page's initialization code. So the test script enters something, the page finishes initialization and clears the field (initial values). It happens quite often.

It's a bug in the page but unfortunately it's also a common bug. Frontend developers should not enable controls before they are ready to process input, but it's rare that they consider test automation requirements. However regular users with slow internet connection could run into this issue too (you can try reproducing the issue manually with Chrome/Chromium developer tools, with 3G network throttling).

A way to work around it could be to:

```
await page.goto('https://somelogin.page', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
```

Warning: In case of a long-polling page that could cause problems though.

Alternatively, if there is something about the page that changes visually once it's fully loaded, then you could wait explicitly for that condition. For example if the focus is put on the username field as soon as the page is ready to accept user input, you could await that selector like:

`await page.waitForSelector('#username:focus');`

... before starting to enter credentials.